# C# BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged doesn't get fired until end of function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a method in my class that has some loops inside.
Main purpose of this method is converting some files so I put a progressbar in my form that should get updated after each file has been converted.

I tried every possible combination and I read everything I could but I couldn't solve this issue.

```
void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    converterProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

is called only after the main loop of my method has been executed.

This is my method:

```
public string Convert()
{
    convertBtn.Enabled = false;
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    totalCount = files.length;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
    }
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        countFile++;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            class1.DoJob();
        }

        using (// some code))
        {
            using (//some other code))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (// again some code)
                    {
                        // job executing
                    }
                }
                catch (exception
                {

                }   
            }
        }
        convertedVideosL.Text = txtToUpdate;
        convertedVideosL.Refresh();
    }
    countFile = countFile + 1;
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
    countFile = -1;
    return outputFile;
}
```

And here are the `BackgroundWorker` Event Handlers:

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= totalCount; i++)
    {
        if (bw.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            int progress = Convert.ToInt32(i * 100 / totalCount);
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progress, i);
        }
    }
}

void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    converterProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == false)
    {
        convertedVideosL.Text = "Finished!";
    }
    else
    {
        convertedVideosL.Text = "Operation has been cancelled!";
    }
}
```

But I cannot get to update the progress bar for every file that is converted.
It waits for the foreach loop to end and then calls `bw_ProgressChanged`.

If I put `RunWorkerAsync()` inside the foreach loop an exception is thrown that says the `BackgroundWorker` is busy and cannot execute other tasks.

It seems to me obvious that `DoWork()` only executes a for loop then it shouldn't be aware of the conversion going on but `ProgressChanged` should be fired by `ReportProgress(progress,i)`.

Could please someone explain me why and help me with a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the code you have posted, I think you have a misunderstanding of BackgroundWorker. The work is supposed to happen inside BackgroundWorker (i.e. move the logic from Convert to bw_DoWork). THen on each iteration of the loop (inside DoWork!) trigger the ReportProgress method.

Comment: could you please elaborate it a little more? Because I tried to run the code inside DoWork but how i trigger the ReportProgress method after the loop? Where do i put RunWorkerAsync?

Comment: There are a lot of things that you need to change in order to make this working. You should run your Convert method in bw_DoWork, but should not access controls inside (like chk, convertedVideosL) and no MessageBox-es. You should call bw.ReportProgress from there and handle it in bw_ProgressChanged, where you can update your UI. Frankly, it would be much easier to make all this working with `async/await`, do you have that option?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the conversion is not executed by the instance of the `BackgroundWorker` type. The conversion should be called from the `DoWork` event handler.

Please consider extracting the conversion-related functionality:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
}
foreach (string file in files)
{
    // Details...
}
```

into the separate method. After that just call the method from the `DoWork` event handler.

Pseudo-code to demonstrate the idea:

```
public void StartConversion()
{
    ...
    TWorkerArgument workerArgument = ...;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(workerArgument);
    // No message box here because of asynchronous execution (please see below).
}

private void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    e.Result = Convert(worker, (TWorkerArgument)e.Argument);
}

private static TWorkerResult Convert(BackgroundWorker worker, TWorkerArgument workerArgument)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
    }

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        // Details...
        worker.ReportProgress(percentComplete);
    }

    return ...;
}

private void BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Show the message box here if required.
}
```

Please replace the `TWorkerArgument` and `TWorkerResult` types appropriately.

Also, please refer to the example which uses the `BackgroundWorker` class for the additional details: [How to: Implement a Form That Uses a Background Operation, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Now it's getting confusing :) It's the first time I try to implement the backgroundworker, as I want to learn this feature, but I cannot follow your code (my mistake of course), with TWorkerResult and TWorkerArgument.Could you please make it a bit simpler?

Comment: @Daniel, `TWorkerArgument` is the type of the data that you want sent to the `BackgroundWorker`, and `TWorkerResult` is the type of data you want returned. Sergey can't tell you what they should be because you have not told us what your data is nor what you are doing with that data.

Comment: @DanielEthereal, I can only guess. Could you please clarify the input and output of the conversion? It seems the input is `folder` path and the output is `outputFile` (?) path.